# Bootstrap modal form is committing twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal form:

```
<div id="commentModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(Comment.new, remote: true, html: {"data-type" => :json}, :validate => true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field(:illustration_id, :value => @illustration.id) %>
      <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => current_user.id) %> 
      <%= f.text_area(:comment, :id => "comment_message") %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-custom-primary' %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

When I submit the comment is added to the db twice, here is the log.  Do you see why this is happening?  Can I provide any other code to help?

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 10:58:32 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asdfasdfasdfasdfasasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf", "comment"=>{"illustration_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"Test comment"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (36.8ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (78.6ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("comment", "created_at", "illustration_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["comment", "Test comment"], ["created_at", Sat, 13 Jul 2013 14:58:32 UTC +00:00], ["illustration_id", 1], ["updated_at", Sat, 13 Jul 2013 14:58:32 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (38.7ms)  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 163ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 154.1ms)


Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 10:58:32 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asdfasdfasdfasdfasasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf", "comment"=>{"illustration_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"Test comment"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (36.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (36.9ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("comment", "created_at", "illustration_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["comment", "Test comment"], ["created_at", Sat, 13 Jul 2013 14:58:32 UTC +00:00], ["illustration_id", 1], ["updated_at", Sat, 13 Jul 2013 14:58:32 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (38.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 116ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 111.7ms)
```

As requested, the comment controller create method:

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And new method:

```
def new
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Do you have any actions (filters) happening before or after the submit?

Comment: @ErminDedovic, no, everything is vanilla in the comments scaffold.  That modal is called from illustrations/show/:id and that view contains other partials that sort lists, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you have `form_for(Comment.new,...)` instead of `form_for(@comment,...)`?

Comment: You should clarify that this is Rails, in you title and content.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is remote :true for ajax submission call. Remove remote :true option from form tag and try normal form submit..surely it works

otherwise If u need ajax submit, please refer this [Jquery Rails 3... form submits twice... deletes twice... help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747236/jquery-rails-3-form-submits-twice-deletes-twice-help/9627690#9627690)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it ended up being pretty sneaky. I was rendering a form inside a modal and it was submitting twice. It ended up being that when I was rendering that content, I was doing so with a layout and thus including all the JS etc again - effectively double-binding the form. What was really surprising is that the form rendered fine - not obviously showing the rest of my app inside the modal.

I fixed it by rendering the modal without a layout ie. in my controller:

```
render layout: false
```